# Get value from confirm box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

How do I get the value of the confirm box selected:

I have this code:

```
string scriptString = "<script language='JavaScript'> ";
scriptString += "confirm ('Are you sure you want to Close this period.')";
scriptString += "</script>";
Response.Write(scriptString);
```

Is there a way to determine if you select yes or no?

Comment: I think you really really need to clarify. Where do you want to know if they said yes or no? On the server or only in the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = confirm('...')
alert(x)
```

or

```
string scriptString = "<script language='JavaScript'> ";
scriptString += "var x = confirm ('Are you sure you want to Close this period.')";
scriptString += "alert(x)";            
scriptString += "</script>";
Response.Write(scriptString);
```

Comment: so how do i put x in if condition.... for the value i get.. sorry for the questions.. u have been really helpful..

Comment: OK = true, Cancel = False. Javascript pretty well follows C syntax so if you know how to build a IF statement in .net, it's the same for JS.

Comment: if i remove alert(x) line it works... so i get a pop up with ok cancel... now my question is how to put if condition that cancel was selected so that it returns without solving further code... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Confirm returns a boolean value indicating ok or cancel (`true` means ok, `false` means cancel).

You can use it like this:

```
if(confirm ('Are you sure you want to Close this period.')) {
  //they clicked ok
}
else {
  //they clicked cancel
}
```

read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.confirm

Comment: the above code is not working.. error: confirm does not exist in current context. i also tried if (window.confirm("Want to see my mood ring?"))... this too is not working... it also said it wont work on chrome. thanks though

Comment: Confirm works fine in chrome. You can see a working example of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/tRUhU/

Comment: hey.. thanks at least my that doubt is cleared.. as you can see i am coding in asp.net.. so i am using the code i have written.. but when i put your code in visual studio it does not recognize confirm.. instead takes it as normal variable.. please help..

Comment: What i have written is javascript - it needs to be run in a  browser, not on the server - that goes for all of it, including the if sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result of the confirm in a hidden field value like this:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")==true){
    hiddenField.value = 'true';
    return true;
} else {
    hiddenField.value = 'false';
    return false;
}
```

and then fetch the value of the hidden field from C#

Comment: Just FYI; please do not include 'signatures' or other unrelated text in your questions/answers. I've edited them out for you :)